# Bitbucket, accidentally pulled wrong branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I happened to pull the wrong branch as I was supposed to pull the master branch but ended up pulling the development branch. This did merge my local repo. However, I would not like to merge the Bitbucket repo. Is there any way to reverse the pull or delete the merge request (see image)?

[image]

EDIT:

I haven't pushed any changes to my Bitbucket yes (as stated in the image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset` will help you achieve this. More info at [man git-reset](https://gitirc.eu/git-reset.html).

In this specific case you are looking to reset your branch so that it points to the first parent of the merge commit, which is the commit on `master` right before the merge.

First, run `git status` to make sure you have no uncommitted changes, as the next command will **delete** them.

Then proceed to reset to the first parent:

`git reset --hard HEAD^`

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure: 'git status' tells me "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits." Then, doing the 'git reset --hard HEAD^' will delete these 3 and reset it?

Comment: No. It will delete only the last one, i.e, the merge commit.

Comment: The output from `git status` you want to look for is "nothing to commit, working tree clean". If you have this, you are good to go. The "Your branch is ahead [...]" is because you have commits locally that have not yet been pushed, one is the merge, and the two others are commits you had since earlier but had not yet pushed.